# Formating date in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to format date currently it's like `2014-08-01 00:00:00.000` and I want like this   `20140801`.

I have tried this and its not working for me.

```
SELECT 
    Null, Null, MemberID, FirstName,  
    MiddleInit, LastName, Address1, Address2,  
    City, [State], ZipCode, PhoneNumber, Email, RelationshipCode ,
    CONVERT(varchar(10), BirthDate, 112) AS BirthDate, Gender, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), CoverageEff, 112) AS CoverageEff, 
    CONVERT(varchar(10), CoverageTerm, 112) AS CoverageTerm ,
    Demographics, PolicyNumber, SchoolName, SchoolID
FROM 
    #HealthiestyouList
```

Result:

```
2014-08-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: "its not working for me" is not working for me. Please explain how it is not working.

Comment: What does SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), BirthDate, 112) return in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the data types Date or a variant of datetime? Because this works for me as it should:

```
DECLARE @DateValue DATETIME = '2014-08-01 00:00:00.000'

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), @DateValue, 112)
```

Returns: 20140801

Comment: data type is date time

Comment: Can you run my example on your computer and see if you get the same output I do?

Comment: Please edit your question include the output of your query so we can see the results.

Comment: It worked i was trying to insert the values to stagger table and data type in stagger table was date time.